# Is there a grunt plugin to append text to a string inside files?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, append

I have a set of files that I want to minify (I already have a grunt task for that) but before minifying them I want to append .min at the end of all the `require` functions so that the files point to the minified version.

I want to replace this:

```
const myModule = require('./my-module');
```

with this:

```
const myModule = require('./my-module.min');
```

so that when I minify this files and add the `.min.js` to the module file it finds the correct file.

I found the plug-in [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace) but I can't find a way to append (not even matching a string and replacing it with the samestring plus the `.min`)

How do can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, modifying code inside of a build pipeline is a bad practice.

I would recommend using a conditional import statement instead.  So your code would be changed to something like:

```
if(is_production){
  const myModule = require('./my-module');
} else {
   const myModule = require('./my-module.min');
}
```

You can then add the `is_production` variable in a number of ways:

1. As an Environment Variable at Runtime.
2. Using the existing `NODE_ENV` variable.
3. In Gulp, by appending a simple `is_production = true` line to the beginning.